# Why is using hardcoded minutes in DateAdd way faster than using a field's value?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Dealing with a SQL issue and I'm not a SQL person, so need some guidance.

Given the SQL statement below, note that the first one uses a hardcoded value of "-360" in the DateAdd function, whereas the second uses a field value (OFFSET) that exists on every record (which has the value of either "-360" or "-300" depending on DST time of year).

Running the first query is extremely fast, while the second takes about 40 seconds longer.

Can someone tell me what the difference is that takes the second so much longer to execute, and because I HAVE to use that record's value and not hard code it, how can I speed up that query?

Query 1 (FAST):

```
SELECT 0 AS 'TempIndex', COUNT(*) AS 'TotalLY'
FROM CLOGS15 h 
WHERE h.EVTYPE = 1 
AND DateAdd(minute, -360, h.EVDATE) BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2015-01-24 00:00:00.000'
```

Query 2 (SLOW):

```
SELECT 0 AS 'TempIndex', COUNT(*) AS 'TotalLY'
FROM CLOGS15 h 
WHERE h.EVTYPE = 1 
AND DateAdd(minute, OFFSET, h.EVDATE) BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2015-01-24 00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could only imagine that the issue is sargability (the user of an index).  However, I thought that `dateadd()` would prevent the use of an index.  If you want to fix this though, perhaps this will work:

```
SELECT 0 AS TempIndex, COUNT(*) AS TotalLY
FROM CLOGS15 h 
WHERE h.EVTYPE = 1 AND offset = 360 AND
      DateAdd(minute, -360, h.EVDATE) BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-24'
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 AS TempIndex, COUNT(*) AS TotalLY
FROM CLOGS15 h 
WHERE h.EVTYPE = 1 AND offset = 300 AND
      DateAdd(minute, -300, h.EVDATE) BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-24';
```

EDIT:

Oops, the above returns two rows and you want one.  So, use a subquery:

```
SELECT TempIndex, SUM(TotalLY) as TotalLY
FROM (SELECT 0 AS TempIndex, COUNT(*) AS TotalLY
      FROM CLOGS15 h 
      WHERE h.EVTYPE = 1 AND offset = 360 AND
            DateAdd(minute, -360, h.EVDATE) BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-24'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 0 AS TempIndex, COUNT(*) AS TotalLY
      FROM CLOGS15 h 
      WHERE h.EVTYPE = 1 AND offset = 300 AND
            DateAdd(minute, -300, h.EVDATE) BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-24'
    ) h
GROUP BY TempIndex;
```

Comment: Made a small edit to your SQL (added a "-" in front of the 360 and 300 in the WHERE clause and it executes now. I get the right total (awesome!), but it outputs a second row now with 0 in each value. Is there a way to get it to only output the single record with the 1 total in the second field (petty I know, but meaningful as it makes my PHP scripting easier).

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think that the difference between the fast and slow queries relies in the index usage.

The SQL Server, in your fast query, might be rewriting your `DATEADD` to enable the index usage on `EVDATE`. As you are adding the date and a constant and checking if it is between to constant dates, it is probably moving the `DATEADD` from the left side (before the `BETWEEN`) to the right side (the dates after `BETWEEN`, reversing the signal of the constant in the `DATEADD`.

Your original is:

```
DateAdd(minute, -360, h.EVDATE) 
  BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
      AND '2015-01-24 00:00:00.000'
```

It might be turning to:

```
h.EVDATE 
  BETWEEN DateAdd(minute, 360, '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000') 
      AND DateAdd(minute, 360, '2015-01-24 00:00:00.000')
```

Which is just the same as your original filter, but enables the index usage and the processing of `DATEADD`, as only two dates need to be processed, instead of all dates in your table.

In your slow query, as your `DATEADD` is using a variable offset, SQL Server can't apply the same rule described above and so it processes all dates in your table with `DATEADD`, which is really slower.

I think you should try a filter like the fast query, maybe something like this:

```
SELECT 0 AS 'TempIndex', COUNT(*) AS 'TotalLY'
FROM CLOGS15 h 
WHERE 1=1 
  AND h.EVTYPE = 1 
  AND 
  (0=1
    OR
    (1=1
      AND OFFSET = -360
      AND h.EVDATE >= DateAdd(minute, 360, '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000') 
      AND h.EVDATE <= DateAdd(minute, 360, '2015-01-24 00:00:00.000')
    )
    OR
    (1=1
      AND OFFSET = -300
      AND h.EVDATE >= DateAdd(minute, 300, '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000') 
      AND h.EVDATE <= DateAdd(minute, 300, '2015-01-24 00:00:00.000')
    )
  )
```

Would be great to this query an index with columns `EVTYPE`, `OFFSET`, `EVDATE` respectively.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation of the "WHY", but the query above returns an incorrect total.

Comment: @SourceMatters Can you try it again, because I had forgotten the signals in the `OFFSET` evaluation...

Comment: Still coming up short about 80 - @Gordon's example gives me the correct value and executes in less than 1 second according to SMMS.